# Determining if there exists a subset in a Array of Integers that sums to a given target value under a couple of conditions

Tags: java, arrays

The Problem:

> Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of
>   the ints, such that the group sums to the given target with this
>   additional constraint: If a value in the array is chosen to be in the
>   group, the value immediately following it in the array must not be
>   chosen.
>
> For eg:-
>
> groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 12) → true
>
> groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 14) → false
>
> groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 7) → false

As you can see in the last case though there exists as subset {2,5} which sums to target value '7' but they are adjacent values and hence can't to chosen together. **Also there is another condition that you can't use a local variable.**

I came up with the solution below:

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if(start==nums.length)
        return target==0;
    if(start==nums.length-1&&!(target==0))
        return (target-nums[start]==0);


    if(target==0)
       return true;

    if((start<nums.length-1)&&groupNoAdj(start+1, nums, target-nums[start]))
           return groupNoAdj(start+2, nums, target-nums[start]);

   return groupNoAdj(start+1, nums, target);
}
```

But it's failing in case groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4, 2}, 7) **it's returning false when it should actually return true**

Can't really spot what's causing it to fail in this case.

Comment: did you try *debugging* your code?

Comment: Why are you calling two constraints *one condition*? No local variables and non-consecutive testing for sum validation.

Comment: Okay there ARE actually 2, so updated the question's summary.

Comment: I don't get the "no local variables" constraint: you can declare all your variables in the class level - it's just more ugly.

Comment: This is just a condition for solving the question not to be used keeping design in view.

Comment: @Anirudh or more like a "hint" to focus on recursion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something in your last condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 ={2, 5, 10, 4};
    int[] arr2 = {2, 5, 10, 4};
    System.out.println(groupNoAdj(0, arr1, 12)); // prints true
    System.out.println(groupNoAdj(0, arr2, 7));  // prints false
}

public static boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

    if(target == 0)
        return true;

    if(start == nums.length)
        return target==0;

    if(start == nums.length-1)
        return target-nums[start] == 0;

    return
            groupNoAdj(start+2, nums, target-nums[start]) || // either pick the "current" item (and skip the "next") 
            groupNoAdj(start+1, nums, target);               // or don't pick it
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alfasin for this solution though it fixes the case in the question but now it fails for -->groupNoAdj(0, {9}, 0)    should return true but it's returning false

Comment: @Anirudh if you want to allow the "empty subset" add a condition that if `target == 0` always return true

Comment: @Anirudh not really, I wrote "always" which means that this condition should become the first condition. The case you describe falls in `start == nums.length-1` and since this condition was checked before `target == 0` it returned false. The updated answer should work.